# Register multiple Siri shortcut at once

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, siri, sirishortcuts

I wrote some code which try to register multiple Siri shortcut at once by iterating enum values

When I run the code and open settings app, it only shows the last registered shortcut.

How should I register multiple Siri shortcut at once?

```
static func registerSiriShortcut(to responder: UIResponder) {

    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
      let cases = SiriShortcutType.allCases
      for type in cases {

        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: type.siriActivityType)
        activity.title = type.siriShortcutTitle
        activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true

        responder.userActivity = activity
        responder.userActivity?.becomeCurrent()
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems okay to me. Generally, Settings->Siri shows only the recent registered shortcuts. If you go to Settings->Siri->All shortcuts, you will see the all names there.

As you mention in your code `activity.isEligibleForSearch = true` Alternatively, go to your phone search from swipe right from home and type the shortcut, you should see the shortcut item's popup too.

EDIT 1: Proof of my Code:

1. Info.plist: You need to mention how many NSUserActivityTypes:

   ```
   <Key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
   <array> 
   <string>com.rio.SiriShortcuts.makeGreen</string>
   <string>com.rio.SiriShortcuts.makeRed</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. Enum class:

   ```
   enum SiriShortcutType {
   case makeRed
   case makeGreen

   var siriActivityType: String {
       switch self {
           case .makeRed:
           return "com.rio.SiriShortcuts.makeRed"
           case .makeGreen:
           return "com.rio.SiriShortcuts.makeGreen"
       }
   }

   var siriShortcutTitle: String {
       switch self {
       case .makeRed:
           return "Make View Red"
       case .makeGreen:
           return "Make View Green"
       }
   }

   var color: String {
       switch self {
       case .makeRed:
           return "red"
       case .makeGreen:
           return "green"
       }
   }

   static let allCases:[SiriShortcutType] = [.makeRed, .makeGreen]
   }
   ```
3. Now my register method in VC (called by button action):

   ```
    func registerSiriShortcut() {
   if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
       let cases = SiriShortcutType.allCases
       var suggestions: [INShortcut] = []
       for type in cases {

           let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: type.siriActivityType)
           activity.userInfo = ["color" : type.color]
           activity.title = type.siriShortcutTitle
           activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
           activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
           activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(type.siriActivityType)
           suggestions.append(INShortcut(userActivity: activity))
       }
       INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
   }
   }
   ```

**Edit 1**: INShortcut supports multiple Siri Shortcuts: See the updated registerSiriShortcut().

Comment: @Bigair, Please post your SiriShortcutType enum in your question post. I will run in my code.

Comment: Is the function makeView(activity: activity) essential?
I implemented your code(without the the method above) but still only the last one from allCases shows up on settings app

Comment: @Bigair, makeview is not essential. But you must launch your app and run the registerSiriShortcut() at least once and exit from app.

Comment: I exactly copied(except siri activity type string) your code and called from vc on button tap.  The setting app still shows only last one of the allCases.

Do you mean by exit as to go background or actually wait 10+ till the app's memory is cleaned?(probably not really matters but jus in case)

Comment: did you run the code on simulator or on a real device?

Comment: Tested in the simulator. Did you get the different result?

Comment: I also tested on simulator but was only showing last one of enum array.  I'll upload my project.

Comment: @Sergio, if possible share your sample project in github/gdrive, I will try to help.

Comment: @RazibMollick I can't share the code, is not mine. But I am doing everything as you say in this answer. Everything but the makeView method, that I am assuming is irrelevant for me. Thanks